# WPF validation, evaluating more than one UI controls

Tags: wpf, validation

I have the following simplified UI:
A groupBox with basically three textboxes as follows:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="Parameter1" Margin="5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="SubParameter1:" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplate}" Height="20">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Parameter.Parameter1" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:ValidationRuleValue1 
                                ValidationStep="RawProposedValue">

                            </local:ValidationRuleValue1>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="SubParameter2:" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Height="20">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Parameter.Parameter2" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:ValidationRuleValue2 
                                ValidationStep="RawProposedValue">

                            </local:ValidationRuleValue2>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="SubParameter3:" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="5" Height="20">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Parameter.Parameter3" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:ValidationRuleValue3 
                                ValidationStep="RawProposedValue">

                            </local:ValidationRuleValue3>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
```

I have implemented validation for each textbox using simple custom validation rules. The first one is given as example.

```
 public class ValidationRuleValue1 : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        //validation here
        return new ValidationResult(true, "");
    }
}
```

My viewmodel is simply:

```
private Parameter parameter;

    public Parameter Parameter
    {
        get
        {
            return parameter;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != parameter)
            {
                parameter = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Parameter");
            }
        }
    }
```

and the model:

```
public class Model
{
    public class Parameter
    {
        public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
        public string Parameter2 { get; set; }
        public string Parameter3 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I would like to validate each input value in combination with the other two. For example all text boxes should have filled-up values or all should be empty. I understand this can be accomplished by the technique mentioned [here](https://michlg.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/wpf-custom-validationrule-with-an-additional-parameter/):

The thing is I would like the trigger of the validation to be the LostFocus event from all the three textboxes (my UI has other input controls too). So, as long as the focus remains in one of these three text boxes, no validation should be triggered. On top of that, the error template should be marking the whole groupBox (since there is actually only one validation) and not on each textbox individually, as it is in the given example.

Can someone give an idea of how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution for that is [BindingGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindinggroup?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was asking for... Thanx!
Another useful link with a sample project is also here
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vinsibal/2008/08/12/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-bindinggroups-with-item-level-validation/